# I Need Help Please With Monero GUI wallet issue

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc, mymonero, monero-forks

please help, I exchanged BTC to Monero using changehero.io and changenow.io, i am still yet to receive the funds on my xmr for two days now. I had two separate transactions, no one is reflecting on my XMR GUI wallet

I contacted the two exchangers and I was told to contact Monero Team, that the transaction was successful.

I have been trying to reach out to Monero Support Team from telegram and other platforms but they all rippers requesting upfront payment before they can help me.

Please help me track my funds with the transaction hashes and id below Thanks for your swift response. I will appreciate if I can get help with this

1. Tx Hash: aeaa3f743dee99700606920455a878deb36eca7947ceba268098839715ec7ef7
   Tx ID: 1f3f617bf93ef771
2. tx Hash:
   e35832a827af9228e3d5f9e2e147311e6dfacf4e706fe2dbc0e322cb88108385
   tx ID: 6b0b93cd10656e
   tx wallet:
   46T9xRy7pU1j8WgS3Yib8PFBnjhb4jfSR4iaEKYmX774j4udgmeFvuZ5nGd6DaetXyfiokt7PUFg5bzmC1QLSNzzA5Vyk6G

Comment: Looks like a valid transaction with 400+ confirmations.  Is your wallet AND node fully synced? Can takes days if starting from scratch on a non-SSD.

Comment: Oh, for future reference, you should use sub-addresses for receive.  That 4X address is the main address.  But baby steps.

Comment: This is not really the place for a help desk kind of question. Best is to ask on reddit (/r/monero) or Freenode (#monero) where you can have some back and forth.